# Change color of text based on suits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A guy helped me to this func, so now I want to change based on a for loop and based on `green`, `blue`, `black`, based on flop suits, if card is a club = green, etc, any helps TY

EXAMpLE
[image]

> ```
> function changeColor(cel, flop) {
>
>   const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
>   const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
>   const range = sheet.getRange(cel);
>   
>   const black = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
>     .setForegroundColor("black")
>     .build();
>
>   const blue = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
>     .setForegroundColor("blue")
>     .build();
>
>   const green = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
>     .setForegroundColor("green")
>     .build();
>
>   const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
>   .setText(flop)
>   .setTextStyle(0, 2, black)
>   .setTextStyle(3, 5, blue)
>   .setTextStyle(6, 8, green)
>   .build();
>
>   range.setRichTextValue(richText); 
> }
> ```

---

First ss on database sheet
Second on reports tab after query

[image: On DB...]
[image: On form Query applied..]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? For example, what are your showing image and your script?

Comment: I think what you are saying is the flop contains suits in any order.  And based on the order set the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

Assuming a cell contains text representing three cards.  Each card seperated by a space. Change the color of the card based on the suit ♠ (black), ♥ (red), ♦ (blue), ♣ (green).

In my example I could have used Range.setRichTextValues() since the cell are contiguous but chose not to because I don't know the OP's intended use.

[image]

**Script**

```
function flop() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for( let i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
      let cell = 'B'+(i+1).toString();
      changeColor(cell,values[i][0]);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function changeColor(cell,flop) {
  try {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let cards = flop.split(' ');
    const black = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("black")
      .build();

    const red = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("red")
      .build();

    const blue = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("blue")
      .build();

    const green = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("green")
      .build();

    let colors = [];
    let range = [];
    let j = 0;
    for( let i=0; i<cards.length; i++ ) {
      let card = cards[i];
      let suit = card.charAt(card.length-1);
      switch(suit) {
        case '♠':
          colors.push(black);
          break
        case '♥':
          colors.push(red);
          break
        case '♦':
          colors.push(blue);
          break
        case '♣':
          colors.push(green);
          break
      }
      range.push([j,j+card.length]);
      j = j+card.length+1;
    }

    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
    richText = richText.setText(flop);
    range.forEach( (card,i) => { richText = richText.setTextStyle(card[0],card[1],colors[i]); } );
    richText = richText.build();

    sheet.getRange(cell).setRichTextValue(richText);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newTextStyle())
- [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newRichTextValue())
- [Range.setRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValue(RichTextValue))

Comment: Ty alot for it! Works perfectly, but, epic fail after query function haha all back to black :(

Comment: What query function?  Its not in your OP.

Comment: after color my flops with your function, i used it with a query func on another sheet, but the colors don't come with query, just black flops hah

Comment: Then you need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: any ideas? Query is really fast and a liked alot to use with a big db, but for better visualisation I need the coloured ones heh , I'll post a answer with some prints!
Ty alot man!

Comment: How are you doing the query? Formula?  If so put the query formula in a cell and use the function to reference that cell that you want to display the final results.

Comment: `=QUERY(SBxBT!A5:R1760, "Select Q, I, K, M, O, R where Q matches '.*"&UPPER($B$1)&".."&UPPER($C$1)&".."&UPPER($D$1)&".*' order by O", 0)`